# How to turn off Ajax navigation in jquery mobile. Because I will to upload image

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have problem to turn off Ajax navigation using data-ajax="false" on your form definition
Where I to setting this.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>textinput</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="PageUploadToMySQL2.php" data-ajax="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ชื่อรถ : <input type="text" name="txtcarNAME"><br>
    ราคา: <input type="text" name="txtcarPRICE"><br>
    Picture : <input type="file" name="filUpload"><br>
    <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

is my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the properties right before jQuery Mobile starts working.

Refer to this, take a look at the `ajaxFormsEnabled` property and `ajaxLinksEnabled` if you need: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a3/#docs/api/globalconfig.html